# Why can I drive InstallShield with Win32::GuiTest on XP but not Windows 7?

Tags: perl, windows-7, installshield

I'm trying to use Win32::GuiTest to test an InstallShield-based uninstall process.  I can open the Control Panel, find the application, and invoke InstallShield but nothing I do seems to let me pick the Remove button in the installer.  So far, I've got:

```
sub uninstall($;$) {
    my ($name, $force) = @_;
    if (! defined($force)) {
        $force=0;
    }

    my @windows;
    # Control Panel window
    my $cpwin;
    my $w;
    my $text;
    # Install Shield window
    my $iswin;

    # Run the Control Panel (In windir, do `control appwiz.cpl`)
    system("cd %windir% && control appwiz.cpl");
    sleep 1;
    print("Opened control panel\n");

    # Get the Window ID of the control panel
    # FIXME - this label is system specifie (W7)
    @windows = FindWindowLike(undef, "Programs and Features", "");
    $cpwin = $windows[0];
    printf("Found CP window ID %x\n", $cpwin);

    # Get the Folder View window of the control panel
    # Find the list of applications
    @windows = FindWindowLike($cpwin, "FolderView");
    $w = $windows[0];

    # Find program in the list
    if (Win32::GuiTest::SelListViewItemText($w, $name) == 0) {
        printf("Could not find '$name'.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    # Invoke the installer for by pressing [Return]
    Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("~");
    # Wait for the "initializing the wizard" window
    @windows = Win32::GuiTest::WaitWindow("InstallShield Wizard", 5);
    # Wait for the real installer window
    sleep 10;
    @windows = Win32::GuiTest::WaitWindow("InstallShield Wizard", 3);
    $iswin = $windows[0];
#    Win32::GuiTest::WaitWindow("Remove");
    printf("Found IS window ID %x\n", $iswin);
#    Win32::GuiTest::SetFocus($iswin);

    @windows = FindWindowLike($iswin, "&Remove", "Button");
    my $remove = $windows[0];
    printf("Found remove button  %x\n", $remove);
    Win32::GuiTest::PushButton($remove);
#    Win32::GuiTest::SetFocus($remove);
#    Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("%r");
#    Win32::GuiTest::MouseClick("Remove",$iswin);
#    Win32::GuiTest::CheckButton($remove);
#    Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{DOWN}{DOWN}");

#    Win32::GuiTest::MouseClick("Next",$iswin);
#    Win32::GuiTest::PushChildButton($iswin, "Cancel");
```

None of the things I've tried (commented out, at the end) seem to have any effect.

I'm using ActivePerl and Win32::GuiTest on Windows 7 if any of that matters.

(Be kind.  My Perl probably sucks.  I have >25 years experience programming but less than a month in Perl.)

Comment: I moved on to trying to drive an NSIS installer.  I can't get that to work, either.  My colleague got it to work on his real XP system but I've got a non-starter in my W7 VM.  OTOH, the notepad example (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GuiTest/lib/Win32/GuiTest/Examples.pm#eg/notepad.pl) works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I'm trying to drive an installer, appears to be a red herring.  On XP (even in a VM), this works fine.  I suspect that the issue is that the installers present dialog boxes whereas Notepad presents a window and those are somehow handled differently in W7 than XP.  I'll come back to why W7 doesn't work but XP is what I have to do right now so that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `Win32::GuiTest::PushButton` method takes the button Text or ID as parameter, not a window/control object. So you don't need to invoke `FindwindowLike` method at all.

But `Win32::GuiTest::PushButton` is looking up buttons from the foreground window only, which might be not properly for all the cases. The `Win32::GuiTest::PushChildButton` should be used.

Please try this way:

```
#@windows = FindWindowLike($iswin, "&Remove", "Button");
#my $remove = $windows[0];
#printf("Found remove button  %x\n", $remove);
sleep 10;
Win32::GuiTest::PushChildButton($iswin, "&Remove", 50);
```

Comment: How about `sleep 10` before push button?